# Usage of Sign Bit in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am reading the book Understanding the Linux Kernel and I came across this code snippet:

```
cmpl  $1,(%eax)
js    SomeLabel
```

I am confused about the use of Sign Flag. When it is set and when it is not set.
If `eax` contains value `1` and the code above is executed what will be the value of sign bit ?

Comment: Not all instructions affect the sign bit. `cmpl` does, and if the result of `cmpl` is negative, the sign bit will be `1`. Otherwise, it will be `0`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_flag. If it's `1`, then the `js` (jump on sign bit) will take the jump. Otherwise, it won't.

Comment: If `eax` contains 1 and the above code is executed you'd probably have a segfault. If `(eax)` contains 1 and the above code is executed, the flags would be updated based on the operation `1 - 1` (== 0), so the sign flag would be cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all instructions affect the sign bit. Which ones affect the bit are described in x86 processor documentation given many places online. Some details about the sign bit (flag) are given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_flag.

In the case of the example, `cmpl` does affect the sign bit. It will compare the operands (subtracts the first argument from the second internally) and, based upon the result of the comparison, set the sign bit to `1` if the comparison is negative, and to `0` otherwise.

The `js` says to jump if the sign bit is set (`1`). So in the case of the example:

```
cmpl  $1,(%eax)
js    SomeLabel
```

Internally the processor will take the value stored at the address in `%eax`, subtract `1` from it, and set the sign bit if the result is negative (*i.e.*, the value at address `%eax` is less than `1`). Then `js` will take the jump if the sign bit is set, and it won't if the sign bit is clear. In other words, it jumps if the value at the address in `%eax` is less than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`JS` jumps if the `SIGN` bit in `EFLAGS` is 1.

According to intel manual:

> **Sign flag** — Set equal to the most-significant bit of the result, which is the sign bit of a signed integer. (0 indicates a positive value and 1 indicates a negative value.)

So, answering to your question, `cmpl $1, (%eax)` will set the sign bit if `eax - 1` is negative. IE: If EAX is 0 or lower (but not `INT_MIN`, because it will underflow).

If eax contains 1, 1 - 1 is 0, so the SIGN BIT will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

A comparison in x86 (and many other architectures) is just a subtract that only affects the flags.

The sign flag after a subtract/comparison is just the sign bit of the result (which does not itself appear anywhere after a comparison).

In this case, it's subtracting 1 from the value at the memory address contained in `eax` (the parentheses signify indirection), and if that results in a negative value, the sign flag will be set.

In other words, it will jump if the value at `eax` is 0 or less but not 0x80000000.